# How to call Scala's HashMap.toArray() from Java?

Tags: java, scala

I use `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap<A,B>` from some Java code and would like to use the Scala-native method `toArray()` to convert the contents (or values) of the map to an array.

I currently use `JavaConversions.asMap()` etc, and then use the traditional, but ugly, Java `toArray(T[])` methods but I would prefer to call the Scala built in method directly instead.

This must be done from Java. Rewriting the code in Scala is not an option.

I am using Scala 2.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a `ClassManifest` for the array type, `T`. This is available from the companion object (see note) for `ClassManifest`. So:

```
itr.toArray(ClassManifest$.MODULE$.fromClass(T.class));
```

In this example, `T` is a real type (not a type parameter). So for example, if `itr` were a `Seq[String]`, you would use this;

```
itr.toArray(ClassManifest$.MODULE$.fromClass(String.class));
```

Because scala's `Map` is actually a bunch of tuples, you would use this:

```
map.toArray(ClassManifest$.MODULE$.fromClass(Tuple2.class));
```

Of course, this gives you a `Tuple2[]`, rather than a `Tuple2<K,V>[]` for the key and values types `K` and `V` respectively. As you are in Java-land, you can cast the raw type

---

**Note**: *accessing the companion object from Java*.

The companion object of a type `M` is available by accessing the static field `M$.MODULE$`

Comment: I assume that ClassManifest$.MODULE$ is the ClassManifest object defined in ClassManifest.scala. I worry about the its documentaton, which says "It is intended for use by the compiler and should not be used in client code."

Comment: As for "the companion object", it is presumably not available for plain Java types (unless Scala is more powerful than I think). In that case, is ClassManifest$.MODULE$.fromClass(SomeType.class) OK to use also for Scala types (like Tuple2, which should already have a predefined Tuple2$.MODULE$)?

Comment: Using (SomeType[])(...some Scala collection).toArray(ClassManifest$.MODULE$.fromClass(SomeType.class)) seems to work well. My only worry is the documentation that claims that ClassManifest is off limits for client code.

Comment: Indeed; in theory, the scala team could change this. However, I doubt they would do so without eliciting community feedback. One more thing: don't forget, scala is just a JAR file at runtime. Just because a new version of scala is released doesn't force you to put it on your classpath

Comment: I thought objects were supposed to have static forwarder methods so you don't need the whole $.MODULE$ thing... don't they work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice:

```
map.toArray(scala.reflect.ClassManifest$.MODULE$.Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the API docs, it seems like you need to supply an argument of type `Manifest` (or of `ArrayTag`, depending on the version) to `toArray`.

Answer (score 0):

calling scala specific methods from java can sometimes be very ugly like in this case. I don't know if there is a better solution to this, but this should work:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap;

import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.reflect.ClassManifest$;
import scala.reflect.ClassManifest;

public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap();
    Object ar = map.<Tuple2<String,String>>toArray((ClassManifest<Tuple2<String,String>>)ClassManifest$.MODULE$.fromClass(new Tuple2<String,String>("","").getClass()));
    System.out.println(ar.toString());
  }
}
```

I don't know of a way in Java to get `Class<Tuple2<String,String>>` without instantiating it first. In scala I would use `classOf[...]` is there an equivalent in java?

Comment: `.class` should get you the class in the same way as `classOf`

Comment: Okay, found a dirty solution ;-). `(Class<Tuple2<String,String>>)(Object)Tuple2.class` works.

Comment: Just drop the type parameters. Type parameters are not relevant to a `Class`.

Comment: If you want to get a typed result it is relevant.

Comment: @drexin - but the types *lie*. There's no such thing as a `T<U>[]` and code should not behave as if there is